# How to use VictoryChart to draw axes for VictoryBar

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, jsx, victory-charts

I am trying to draw a bar chart with Victory library for React.
When I just call the VictoryBar component it renders the bar chart correctly. But when I wrap it inside a VictoryChart component to draw chart axes it doesn't render.

My code is as follows

```
<div style={styles.dataWrapper}>
    <svg viewBox='-100 -20 1000 800'> 
       <VictoryChart>
          <VictoryBar
             width={500}
             height={500}
             standalone={false}
             padding={50}
             barWidth={50}
             theme={VictoryTheme.material}
             colorScale={colorScale}
             data={agentData}
             x={d => d.agent}
             y={d => d.reqCount}
             labels={d => `${d.agent} : ${d.reqCount}`}
             /> 
        </VictoryChart>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Putting `standalone={false}` to VictoryChart solved the problem. But however according to [Victory docs](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-chart#standalone) VictoryChart sets standalone={false} for all of its children.

.